# Circuitikz - Adding adjustable / variable indication arrow to component

Tags: circuitikz

I'm trying to create an RF block diagram using circuitikz and was wondering what the best way of adding an arrow to indicate that it has an adjustable/variable parameter would be.

E.g. turn this

```
\node[oscillator, label=LO]{};
```

[image]

into this

```
\node[v_oscillator, label=LO]{};
```

[image]

Can I somehow create a new component, e.g. some "v_oscillator" that already has this arrow? Or is there some alternative way that is simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, you should be able to use the ["generic tunable arrow"](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsubsection.4.11.2) --- in practice, there is a small <strike>bug</strike>glitch when the element has the `center` anchor on a side (happens in several components, for easiness of positioning). So you have to patch the thing ([I'll fix it](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/617) in the next release, 1.5.0).

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\def\ctikztunablearrow{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\ctikztunablearrow@full}{\ctikztunablearrow@simple}}%
\def\ctikztunablearrow@simple{\ctikztunablearrow@full[]}%
\def\ctikztunablearrow@full[#1]#2#3#4#5{%
    % add tunable arrow to a component
    % relative thickness, relative length, rotation from axis, name of the component
    \scope
    \draw
    \pgfextra{\pgfcirc@set@arrows{tunable}{}{latexslim}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{#2\pgflinewidth}} [#1]
        let \p1=($(#5.north east)-(#5.south west)$), \p2=($(#5.east)-(#5.west)$),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {atan2(\y2,\x2)} in
        % node[above]{\n1, \n2}
        ($(#5.west)!0.5!(#5.east)$) ++({\n2+(#4)}:{-0.5*(\n1)*(#3)}) -- ++({\n2+(#4)}:{(\n1)*(#3)});
    \endscope
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [oscillator](M) at(0,0){};
    \ctikztunablearrow[color=blue, densely dashed]{1}{1.2}{45}{M}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]